What is the anime movie with a sick guy who was able to kill vampires with his bright appearance?
It's from somewhere between the late '90s and early '00s. There was a gang that killed vampires (a vampire-killing gang?). They wore armor somewhat similar to Warhammer and Warcraft at the same time, and their weapons consisted of hammers, swords, and guns.
Also, there was a machine gun on top of their fully armored van, I think.
One scene that I really remembered involved a guy with some health condition who always lay in bed surrounded by medical devices (maybe their van was an ambulance?). Although he was pitiful and everybody felt bad about him once, in a very bad situation, he helped his friends with vampires.
They were pursuing a branch of vampires in a car chase. The vampires, though, were tough and did some madness that the protagonist group couldn't help themselves with.
At some point, the sick guy stood up at the top of the car and started glowing and emitting light beams. One vampire opened his jacket, under which presumably was a space of everything-absorbing endlessness. The sick guy's beams pierced through the vampire, and the vampire wasn't happy about it.
This is mostly all that I can remember. To help with recognition, I'd like to make an illustration of the scene (I'm not an artist):

I watched it when I was ~6 and still, after 20 years, sometimes remember it.

For reference, OP has since reposted this on SciFi.SE and found the answer there.

@F1Krazy Then the question is what point reopening would have if it then ultimately needs to be closed as a cross-site duplicate again (other than making a point about injudiciously reopening everything).

Some of the details are wrong, but it reminds me of Vampire Hunter D: Bloodlust.

@ParkerMacInnis That's the answer that was given and accepted on the cross-posted question on SciFi.SE.

The real issue here isn’t the post being undeleted and reopened. It’s that a moderator closed and immediately deleted it, along with several other questions. This isn’t typical practice in SE sites—usually, closed questions aren’t deleted right away. Deleting them so quickly after closing them prevents commenting, cutting off all discussion and prevents comments like F1Krazy’s, which only showed up once the post was undeleted. I’m not sure why we’re seeing this trend of overzealous deletion, but it’s very unnecessary and making it harder for the community to engage with these posts.

@galacticninja It is very much practice if the question is entirely u nsuitable for the site. Closed questions stay undeleted in order to be improved into appropriate questions. When that is impossible, there is no reason to keep them around for 9 days longer since closure is normally a pre step deletion. It's also hardly a "trend". It has been done since the very beginning and isn't done anymore to ID questions because they're on-topic now.

Cross-posting is not encouraged especially when it is answered there.

Vampire Hunter D: Bloodlust (2000)
The movie you're recalling is Vampire Hunter D: Bloodlust, released in 2000. It features D, the titular character, and the Marcus brothers (the vampire-hunting gang you mentioned) pursuing an antagonist vampire who has kidnapped a woman.
The film includes a chase scene where D and the Marcus brothers race after the antagonist. As you remembered, the Marcus brothers use an armored vehicle. It's called the "atomic bus," which more closely resembles a tank than a van. This aligns with your memory of a fully armored vehicle used by the vampire hunters.

The guy with the health condition is named "Grove," a member of the Marcus brothers. Despite his frailty, Grove possesses powerful psychic abilities. During a pivotal moment, Grove uses his psychic powers to project energy beams from his "ghost" form, similar to the "glowing and emitting light beams" you recalled.
Here's a relevant scene from the film showing Grove using his powers:





A scene you described involves a confrontation with Bengé, a mutant hired by the antagonist vampire. Bengé, while not a vampire himself, has the ability to create a void-like space, which he uses to trap D. This likely corresponds to your memory of a vampire opening his jacket to reveal "a space of everything-absorbing endlessness."

Here is the plot from Wikipedia (I've highlighted the parts relevant to your query):

In the middle of the night, Charlotte Elbourne, a young human woman, is abducted by Baron Meier Link, a vampire nobleman. Charlotte's wealthy father, John, hires D, a dhampir, to rescue her, dead or alive.
At the same time, Charlotte's older brother Adam hires the Marcus Brothers, composed of their leader Borgoff, the hulking Nolt, the blade master Kyle, the frail/physically bedridden psychic Grove, and Leila, a woman who holds a grudge towards vampires. D and the Marcus Brothers race after Meier, learning that Charlotte was not kidnapped but chose to accompany him out of love for the vampire.
Meier hires the mutant Barbarois to guard him, consisting of the shapeshifter Caroline, the shadow manipulator Bengé, and the werewolf Mashira. Nolt is killed by Bengé, resulting in the brothers confronting the Barbarois in their home territory. At the same time, D visits them. Grove causes a large ruckus using his psychic powers, and D becomes trapped in a void that Bengé creates. D escapes the void, and the Marcus Brothers avenge Nolt by killing Bengé. They then travel to a nearby western town, where Leila convinces the local sheriff to stop D. Fortunately, D is saved by an old man who recalls the dhampir rescuing him as a child from a vampire. […]

The protagonist, D, is a dhampir (half-vampire, half-human). Your illustration closely resembles D's appearance, complete with his wide-brimmed hat and long coat.


Curious about the downvote(s). Mind sharing why? Did I misidentify the film, or should I add more information? I'm open to improving it.

Sorry, I didn't downvote your great response! I didn't even know it existed till today.
This is true that my question has already been answered there: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/289826/76048

The only thing that I still can't get: Why did Benge scream in terror when Glove attacked him, but in the next scene he looked like nothing happened to him at all?
Is this a goof? Can we mention this in IMDB? I am bothered about it because this question doesn't go out of my head for 20 years and this is the reason I remembered this cartoon for so long.
I probably have to open the original manga for the details of this event

@Rr It might be worth creating a new question about this specific scene. It's been a while since I've watched it myself, so I can't offer much insight. Your comment is making me think it might be time for a rewatch!
